# Finding a homeomorphism between $ B $ and $ B \times B $.

Tags: general-topology

Let $ B = A^{\mathbb{N}} $, where $ A $ is a topological space. Show that $ B $ is homeomorphic to $ B \times B $.

**My failed attempt:** I’m trying to show that there exists a function $ f: B \to B \times B $ such that for any basic open set $ U $ in $ B \times B $, $ {f^{-1}}[U] $ is also open in $ B $. I haven’t been able to find a good function $ f $ to work with. Can someone help, with details, to find such a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\mathbf{x} = ( x_n )_n$ is an element of $B$, map it to $( \mathbf{x}_0 , \mathbf{x}_1 ) \in B \times B$ where $\mathbf{x}_0 = ( x_{2n} )_n$ and $\mathbf{x}_1 = ( x_{2n+1} )_n$. Let's call this function $f$.

To show that $f$ is continuous it suffices to show that $f^{-1} ( V )$ is open for every open set $V$ in some base $\mathcal D$ for $B \times B$. Let's pick the following base:  $\mathcal D$ is the family of all $V_0 \times V_1$ such that $V_0 = \prod_n V_{0,n}$ and $V_1 = \prod_n V_{1,n}$ where each $V_{i,n}$ is open in $A$ and for each $i$ $V_{i,n} = A$ for all but finitely many $n$.

If we have such a set $V_0 \times V_1$, then $f^{-1} ( V_0 \times V_1 ) = \prod_n W_n$ where $$W_n = \begin{cases}
V_{0,\frac{n}{2}}, &\text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
V_{1,\frac{n-1}{2}}, &\text{if }n\text{ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$
It should be straightforward to show that this set in open in $B$.

Conversely, to show that $f^{-1}$ is continuous we just need to show that $f ( U )$ is open for all $U$ in some base $\mathcal B$ for $B$. For this we pick the standard basis $\mathcal B$ for $B = A^{\mathbb N}$ consisting of all $U = \prod_n U_n$ where each $U_n$ is open in $A$, and $U_n = A$ for all but finitely many $A$. Given such a set $U$ we can show that $f ( U ) = ( \prod_n U_{2n} ) \times ( \prod_n U_{2n+1} )$, which can be shown to be open in $B \times B$.

Comment: many thanks for your hint. Here's my attempt: due to the definition of the map, it's clear that $f$ is 1-1 and onto. So now, we pretty much need to show that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is continuous. This is equivalent to show that: $\pi o\ f: X \rightarrow X\times X$ is continuous,  but I stuck on here:P

Comment: can someone please help me further with the proof for continuity? I'm not sure if I prove this correctly: I showed that $\pi_{a}  o \pi o f: \prod {X_{\alpha}: \alpha\in N}\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ is continuous for every $\alpha\in N$, which is true since projection mapping of product topology is always continuous. Thus $ \pi o f$ is continuous, so $f$ is continuous. For $f^{-1}$, I showed that $\pi_{\alpha} o f^{-1}(x_1,x_2) = \pi_{\alpha}(x_0)= (\pi_{a} o \pi_{0})(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_0 = x_1\cup x_2$ ($x_1, x_2$ are two functions).

Comment: @user177196 I've expanded my answer to give more details about the function being a homeomorphism.